# (Thread:1 signal SiGARBT) tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have been creating an RSS Feed and I am getting an error.

When I typed in this code >

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I get an error Thread 1:Signal SIGARBT
I fix this error by typing this.

```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

But this complicated the problem even more because when it works I cannot click on the cell and it will not work and prepare for the segue so when I click on the cell it is not going to the next View Controller. That is even worse so i get rid of.

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

^^^^

This above code is located in viewDidLoad

Once I get rid of that piece of code 
when I open my app I get `Thread 1: Signal SIGARBT` on the line `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

I have tried everything this error is not getting fixed please give a fix to Signal SIGARBT.

This is my full code.

```
//
//  AppMain.m
//  fcffv
//
//  Created by Ajay Venkat on 6/09/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 AJTech. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppMain.h"
#import "AppDetail.h"
@interface AppMain () {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;
}
@end
@implementation AppMain
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bountyboulevardss.eq.edu.au/?cat=3&feed=rss2"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return feeds.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];
    } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [link appendString:string];
    }

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

    }
}

@end
```

Image :
[image: Error]

This is the image ^^^

Guys please help.

Comment: I am not sure what you did. But I can give small guide line. Make the table view delegate first. Then define the cell name in the storyboard. And here you are define the cell inside the cell for row index path. use separate class (NSObject with UITablecell)

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean but I am only 12 years old. So i do  self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self; before the cell?

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/

Comment: @Xcoder> Can you give the full stack trace from debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you give cellIdentifier of the cell in StoryBoard as **@"Cell"** as i can see you have written `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";`

Comment: Well you've earnt it in my about page